# How to find $m$ such that $\sum_{m+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}<c$ for fixed $c$

Tags: summation

I would like to approximate the infinite sum 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$$ up to a precision of $10^{-6}$. For that I want to know at what $m$ I can stop, so that the remaining part will be insignificant. So I would like to find an $m$ such that
$$\sum_{m+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}<10^{-6}$$

I would welcome any hints or links.

Comment: Well, the integral is a fairly good comparison.  suggests you need $m\approx 10^6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to do a lot better than the integral.

As $f(x)=\frac 1{x^2}$ is monotonically decreasing, we get $$\int_m^{\infty}\frac {dx}{x^2}>\sum_{m+1}^{\infty}\frac 1{k^2}>\int_{m+1}^{\infty}\frac {dx}{x^2}$$

Thus $$\frac 1{m}>\sum_{m+1}^{\infty}\frac 1{k^2}>\frac 1{m+1}$$

Taking $m=10^6$ shows that $$\frac 1{10^6}>\sum_{10^6+1}^{\infty}\frac 1{k^2}>\frac 1{10^6+1}$$  So that value suffices but no smaller value will.

Worth remarking that in this case, the exact value of the infinite sum is known (it is $\frac {\pi^2}6$) so there are better ways to approximate it.